# Share button in android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

In my app, i am trying to implement Share button, Which when clicked should give me list of all the social media icons. I was looking at some examples, i like the way media is shared on "WhatApp", u selected the media, click on share, the a window slides up from bottom with the list of social media icons, i saw this kind of implemenatation in othe apps also, and you slide left or right to see more icons. How do i implement something like this in my app. Any examples would be appreciated. below is the screen shot of one of the apps.

[image: one of the screen shots]

Comment: search on google about #Sharing Intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("image/*");// You Can set source type here like video, image text, etc.
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(fileUrl);
                shareIntent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share File Using!"));

            }
        });
```

here `share` is my ImageView

let me know if any query

Comment: thanks for replying, when i try to share the file via any media, I am getting "Couldn't attach file"

Comment: which type of file you are sharing? image, video, gif, etc.

Comment: share your code here

Comment: or change line Uri.parse(fileUrl) to Uri.parse("file://"+fileUrl);

Comment: @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("audio/*");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android:resource://"+getActivity().getPackageName()+"/raw/"+ selectedMediaFile);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
shareIntent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Via!"));
}});'

Answer (score 0):

Firstly set that image on ImageView and then use this code to share the image :-

```
share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(img);
                        if (bmpUri != null) {
                            // Construct a ShareIntent with link to image
                            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
                            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                            // Launch sharing dialog for image
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
                        } else {
                            // ...sharing failed, handle error
                        }
                    }
                });
```

"img" is my image which i want to share.

Comment: You can also set image url in the "img" f..